# SQL Unpivot groups of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, unpivot

Honestly, I'm not even sure if there is a more appropriate function to use to tackle my problem as I'm not familiar with many functions in SQL 2014 besides basic Select, Update, Delete, Insert...

I have this table:

```
RegionID    Price1    Price1New    Efx1Date    Price2    Price2New    Efx2Date
   1         3.5        4.0        10/23/17     3.75       4.5        10/20/17
   2         3.25       4.5        10/21/17     4.25       4.0        10/21/17
```

How can I get the result to be?

```
RegionID    PriceList    Current    NewPrice    EfxDate
   1        Price1        3.5        4.0        10/23/17
   1        Price2        3.75       4.5        10/20/17
   2        Price1        3.25       4.5        10/21/17
   2        Price2        4.25       4.0        10/21/17
```

Comment: Well you have what is known as repeating groups which violates 1NF. This is why you are struggling here. You can use UNPIVOT to do this. Or you could use a UNION ALL for this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a UNION ALL

```
SELECT RegionId, 'Price1' AS PriceList, Price1 AS [Current], Price1New AS NewPrice, Efx1Date AS EfxDate
UNION ALL
SELECT RegionId, 'Price2' AS PriceList, Price2 AS [Current], Price2New AS NewPrice, Efx2Date AS EfxDate
```

Answer (score 1):

As requested, using UNPIVOT notation, the query will be like below

```
--create table T(RegionID int,   Price1  money,  Price1New   money, Efx1Date  date,  Price2  money,  Price2New money,  Efx2Date date)
--insert into T values 
--(1,3.5 ,4.0,'10/23/17', 3.75,  4.5, '10/20/17'),(2,3.25,4.5,'10/21/17', 4.25,  4.0, '10/21/17')

select 
RegionId,
priceList,
[Current],
NewPrice= Case 
            when priceList='Price1'
            then Price1New
            when priceList='Price2'
            then Price2New
          end,
EfxDate= Case 
            when priceList='Price1'
            then Efx1Date    
            when priceList='Price2'
            then Efx2Date    
          end
from
(select * from T)s
unpivot
(
    [Current] for [priceList] in ([Price1],[Price2])
    )up
 order by 1,2
```

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/KWH86687)**</kbd>

Comment: You should not order by ordinal position. If the columns change in your query and you don't also change the order by your query will suddenly have a different order. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal